# INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR on queryMore on node js

Tags: soap-api, node.js, querylocator

I m getting INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR error on using queryMore operation using the Enterprise WSDL on node js.

## Below is the code

```
 client.query({queryString:"Select Id,Name FROM Account ORDER BY Name"},function(err,result2,raw){
            console.log(result2.result.queryLocator);
        client.queryMore(result2.result.queryLocator+'',{batchSize :2000},(err,result) => {
            console.log('temp',err);
        }) ;  

        });
```

Let me know what i m doing wrong ?

Comment: I never used the SOAP API to query records in node, but i know in other libraries you'd only get a queryLocator when you exceed 200 records (i see in the SOAP docs its actually 500 by default, but when there are more records). The queryLocator is not null I assume and done = false?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn correct done = false and queryLocator value is not null but here result2.result.queryLocator value is {accountId}-{Integer} still it is throwing INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR error

Comment: Hmm, like I say never used SOAP in node before so on the basis of what you've said, not sure. I know it doesn't answer your question, but I find the REST API much easier to work with from node....great library called jsforce if you've not seen it.

Comment: @PhilHawthorn thanks for sharing i m also using jsforce but since i m fetching 1lac odd records within 30 seconds so i thought that SOAP API would be better. Can the same be done using jsforce ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely - it uses REST API under the hood to make the query, i've found it to be efficient. Also, you should be able to change the query options header to have a higher batch size (see here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_queryoptions.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Phil